# what does the @Override does in Java?

Tags: java

i wonder what does the @Override does in Java? My program runs properly without it. Netbeans put a yellow line in my method suggesting to use @Override. But even if i ignore the suggestion, my program runs without any error. Well, i'm just curious. thanks for any reply.

Comment: Please do a google search before posting on SO. Here's a description about @Override: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. i'll see to it that i check google first before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is useful for the situation where you think you are Overriding a method but accidentally used the wrong signature.  For example lets say you need to override a class's method that looks like this:

```
public String getProperty(int x, int y) {...}
```

But you accidentally implement:

```
public String getProperty(int x){...}
```

You would not get a compile error for this.  But if you include the @Override annotation on your implementation of that method, then the code will not compile and your IDE will let you know.  So its mainly for safety.

Comment: Yes you would get an error if you don't implement an interface method!

Comment: Good point let me edit with class.  Thanks!

Comment: thank you for a clear explanation.. Mainly for safety reasons. thanks..

Answer (score 2):

It tells indicates to the compiler that the annotated method is overriden, either from a superclass or an interface. Your code will compile without it, but in the event that a method that *doesn't* override anything happens to be using that annotation, the code will fail to compile.

Resource:

- [TheJDK's documentation on `@Override`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html)

Answer (score 0):

Although it complies ok, it's always a good coding practice to use the annotation when you purposely override a method. This will help in avoiding typo's that makes an overridden method looking like just another method.